# Neovim changes permissions for file or directory

Tags: macos, vim, permissions, neovim, access-rights

By accessing a file with use of `sudo nvim . || filename`, it changes permissions for the whole directory, or for a particular file

After, if I will try to access `file/directory` with `VSCode` | `WebStorm`, file has read-only permission

Terminals that I'm using are `iTerm2` and `Warp`

System: Mac OS X

Also, is it possible to change it to access `neovim` without sudo?
As it fails to load plugins without it

Tried to google it, but there is no info related to such problem

Have to manually change permission, if I need other editor